# Exporting blender vertex groups animation to unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, export, blender

I created simple object with some vertex groups and shape keys and added keyframes based on the shape keys. I have problem with exporting this animation to unity. It just shows that there is only one frame in the animations section of this prefab. Do you have any idea what may be source of this problem. I'm new to blender and unity so I might have done some stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually shape key animations do not import to Unity. But shape keys themselves do (in Unity they're called "blend shapes").
They wil show up like this:

[image: pic related]

So what you need to do is animate yourself the blend shapes, via animation or scripting.

You SHOULD read [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BlendShapes.html)